# Subset data frame by row according to length of ngrams

Tags: r, dataframe, split

I have a data frame with many terms (ngrams of different sizes up to fivegrams) and their respective frequencies:

```
df = data.frame(term = c("a", "a a", "a a card", "a a card base", "a a card base ne",
                         "a a divorce", "a a divorce lawyer", "be", "be the", "be the one"), 
                freq = c(131, 13, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 72, 17, 5))
```

Which give us:

```
                 term freq
1                   a  131
2                 a a   13
3            a a card    3
4       a a card base    2
5    a a card base ne    1
6         a a divorce    1
7  a a divorce lawyer    1
8                  be   72
9              be the   17
10         be the one    5
```

What I want is to separate unigrams (terms with only one word), bigrams (terms with two words), trigrams, fourgrams, and fivegrams into different data frames:

For example, "df1" containing only unigrams would look like this:

```
                 term freq
1                   a  131
2                  be   72
```

"df2" (bigrams):

```
                 term freq
1                 a a   13
2              be the   17
```

"df3" (trigrams):

```
                 term freq
1            a a card    3
2         a a divorce    1
3          be the one    5
```

And so on. Any idea? Regex maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split by space count, i.e.

```
split(df, stringr::str_count(df$term, '\\s+'))

#$`0`
#  term freq
#1    a  131
#8   be   72

#$`1`
#    term freq
#2    a a   13
#9 be the   17

#$`2`
#          term freq
#3     a a card    3
#6  a a divorce    1
#10  be the one    5

#$`3`
#                term freq
#4      a a card base    2
#7 a a divorce lawyer    1

#$`4`
#              term freq
#5 a a card base ne    1
```

A solely base R solution (as @akrun mentions), would be,

```
split(df, lengths(gregexpr("\\S+", df$term)))
```

Comment: In addition, it returns a list with five elements (unigrams, bigrams, .... , up to fivegrams). It was just what I was looking for. Many thanks.

Comment: Here is another with `base R` i.e. `split(df, lengths(gregexpr("\\S+", df$term)))`